# Postgres Hours Calculation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have been trying to work this out all week. I have a table with values names start and finish. I need a Postgres query to relay the hours back to me in a nice format.

The original (before hours) query is this

```
select * from public.volass
where linkedass=$request_id 
order by start
```

So when I try and use DiffDate I make it look like

```
select datediff(hours,start,finish), * from public.volass
where linkedass=$request_id 
order by start
```

Postgres then gives me the following error.

```
ERROR:  column "hours" does not exist
LINE 1: select datediff(hours,start,finish), * from public.volass
                        ^
********** Error **********
ERROR: column "hours" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 17
```

1. Do I need to have a field named "Hours" in the system for this to work
2. Even if I add a field named "hours" it still stuffs up
3. Can you steer me in the correct direction to use Difdate

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Postgre's [EXTRACT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

```
SELECT (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM finish - start) / 3600) AS duration, *
FROM public.volass 
WHERE linkedass=$request_id 
ORDER BY start
```